# A strange occurrence in the config timer on STM32F103x

Tags: c, static, microcontroller, stm32

I use this function for config timer on STM32F103RBT6

```
static void TIMER_Config(TIM_TypeDef* timer, uint16_t Period, uint16_t Prescaler, uint16_t ClockDivision, uint16_t CounterMode ,FunctionalState status)
{
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure;

    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = Period;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = Prescaler;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = ClockDivision;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = CounterMode;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(timer, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(timer, status);

    TIM_ClearITPendingBit(timer, TIM_IT_Update);
    TIM_ITConfig(timer, TIM_IT_Update, status);
    TIM_SetCounter(timer, 0);
    TIM_Cmd(timer, status);
}
```

I use this function as follows:

```
TIMER_Config(TIM1, 359, 1, 0, TIM_CounterMode_Up, ENABLE);
```

When I measured the output frequency everything is correct
But when I remove the "static" from the function The output frequency is changed!

I use this code for measured the output frequency

```
void TIM1_UP_IRQHandler(void)
{
    static uint16_t us = 0;

    if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM1, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET)
    {
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM1,TIM_IT_Update);
        GPIO_WriteBit(LED0_Port ,LED0_PIN,!GPIO_ReadOutputDataBit(LED0_Port,LED0_PIN));
    }
}
```

The measured frequency when "static" not removed is 50 kHz
when I remove "static" ,frequency changed to 320 Hz!

<==**UPDATE**==>

This problem exists only on TIM1(Advance Timer) and this problem was not seen on the TIM2(General purpose Timer).

Comment: You most probably have a weakly defined symbol of the same name in some linked library.

Comment: i changed function name to "TIMERrrrrr_Config" but problem not solved

Comment: Do you step into the right function with the right parameters and see everything set the same with the debugger in both cases?